# Missing 'run' button in Airflow UI task instance context menu - how to fix?

Tags: airflow

I set-up a new airflow server on the latest version (2.6.1)
i added one of the example dags
and when I go in the Task Instance Context Menu I am missing the run button

Is it an issue at the airflow.cfg file?

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZu2A.png)

[This is what I should have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYqMj.png)

Comment: Not sure what the answer is but I have the same issue. This is after upgrading to a new version of Airflow and using the AWS managed version (MWAA)

Answer (score 0):

The run button was removed due to a combination of bug/non-compliant code in the feature. The "Clear" action should be used instead.

Source: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/31544.